# linq get recursive list only one level in c#

Tags: c#, linq

Want to be able to extract the first  2 levels of a recursive list.

### TABLE

InventoryTypeId int

Type    nvarchar(50)

ParentId    int

```
public IEnumerable<inventoryTypeModel> getInventoryTypes()
{
    var _type = from d in dbgpsContext.InventoryType
                 where d.ParentId==null
                select new inventoryTypeModel
                {
                    typeid = d.InventoryTypeId  ,
                    type = d.Type,
                    subtypes=???//no sure what goes here
                };

    return _type.ToList(); 
}
```

Comment: By first two levels, do you mean everything whose `ParentId` is 0 and all their children?

Comment: @CompuChip Yes i do mean that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the magic:

```
public IEnumerable<inventoryTypeModel> getInventoryTypes()
{
    var _type = from d in dbgpsContext.InventoryType
                 where d.ParentId==null
                select new inventoryTypeModel
                {
                    typeid = d.InventoryTypeId  ,
                    type = d.Type,
                    subtypes= from s in d
                              where ParentId == d.Id
                              select s.Type
                };

    return _type.ToList(); 
}
```

Hopefully this helps, because i dont know exactly how your models are in relation.

Comment: Could you Add your Model of Inventory type? It would be good for further help

Answer (score 0):

here is the LINQ method chain version

```
public IEnumerable<inventoryTypeModel> getInventoryTypes()
{

 var _type = dbgpsContext.InventoryType.Where(d=> d.ParentId == null).Select(b => new
              {
                Typeid = b.InventoryTypeId  ,
                Type = b.Type,
                Subtypes = dbgpsContext.InventoryType.Where(v=> v.ParentId == b.Id).Select(c => c.Type)
                }).ToList();

 return _type; 
}
```

Comment: I get this error...
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<GPS.Models.gps.inventoryTypeModel>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)